# php's execution time and memory limit

Tags: memory, centos, execution, php

I am using centOS 5 server. i got the error while i was attempting to download 1GB of file from server to my server that

```
maximum execution time exceeded.
```

i opened my php.ini file, it was written there

```
max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60     ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
```

in last line it is written `Maximum amount of memory a script may consume` so what does it mean actually? it will not download more than this per script execution or its about the memory taken by script to be executed (sharing types)
i searched but not got the answer of this. Please if any one can tell me what it mean exactly and how can i be able to download approx 1GB of data through script from other server using PHP.

**EDIT**

code i am using to download the file from server using curl

```
$username = "user";
$password = "pwd";
$url = "http://domain.com/feeds/";

global $ch;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$r = time()-(24*60*60); 
$dateit = date("Ymd", $r);
$file8 = "abc".$dateit.".tbz";
$file3 = "abc".$dateit.".tbz.md5";
$file5 = "xyz".$dateit.".tbz";
$file4 = "xyz".$dateit.".tbz.md5";
$file7 = "lmn".$dateit.".tbz";
$file2 = "lmn".$dateit.".tbz.md5";
$file6 = "pqr".$dateit.".tbz";
$file1 = "pqr".$dateit.".tbz.md5";
$arr = array($file1, $file2, $file3, $file4, $file5, $file6);
for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++)
{

 $url = "http://domain.com/feeds/current-data/".$arr[$i];
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

 $fp = fopen("adminArea/folder1/".$arr[$i], 'w+');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
 curl_exec ($ch);

}
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any idea help link or view will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memory_limit` is the max amount of data the script can have loaded *into memory* at any given time. That means that if you try and read the entire contents of a 1GB file into a **variable**, yes, you'll run into problems.

On the other hand, if you download the file directly to disk (rather than trying to read its contents in your script), it can be streamed through memory piece by piece, and thus you wouldn't necessarily run into memory limitations.

You could also manually read the file chunk by chunk using things like [`fread()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to keep from going over the memory limit at any given time.

Comment: so you mean to say i have to change the pattern of downloading file? i am using curl to download file. and also i dont need to change any of these settings for that?

Comment: You can use the `CURLOPT_FILE` option to have cURL download straight to disk. :) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: i am using the same to do so, but then too i am having this error. should i post another question with the code, as it mean that i have issues in curl request/response?

Comment: No, just edit your answer to show your code. However, note the error you're getting: maximum execution *time* exceeded. That's because `max_execution_time` is set to `30`, which means 30 *seconds* - and it's probably going to take longer than 30 seconds to download a gigabyte of data. You probably need to increase the value of that setting (if you're allowed to).

Answer (score 3):

Most of them are self-explanatory, but I can try to boil them down for you.

- `max_execution_time`: The maximum time the script can run. If you are downloading a 1GB file and the script is running the whole time, bump this value up from `30` to maybe `300`.
- `max_input_time`: Not relevant to your problem.
- `memory_limit`: The amount of RAM that a PHP process can consume. RAM isn't disk space, so as long as your script isn't doing anything memory-intensive like image processing, database operations, or reading your whole 1GB file into RAM, you're fine.

Comment: i am using curl to download the file from the server to mine, so will it be taking much memory space or i dont need to change it only execution_time will do?

Comment: Curl saves to disk. I'd change your `max_execution_time`.